# OxyPlot EventTrigger

Tags: wpf-controls

I am trying to handle event in OxyPlot using EventTrigger. But it does not work like I want.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding PlotModel}" DefaultTrackerTemplate="{x:Null}">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers >
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding  Move}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </oxy:PlotView>

</Grid>
```

And code look's like

```
using OxyPlot;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
namespace WpfApplication14
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public class DataGeneration
    {
        public PlotModel PlotModel { get; set; }
        public ICommand Move { get; set; }
        public int _NumberOf;
        public Dictionary<int, List<int>> Test { get; set; }
        OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries LS;
        Random rnd;
        LinearAxis LA;
        public int EndPosition = 0;
        public DataGeneration(int NumberOf)
        {
        LA = new LinearAxis()
        {
            Position=AxisPosition.Bottom,
            Minimum=0,
            Maximum = EndPosition
        };
            Move = new RelayCommand(() => TestMove());
            _NumberOf = NumberOf;
            rnd = new Random();
            Test = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
            PlotModel = new PlotModel();
            PlotModel.Axes.Add(LA);
            LS = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
            PlotModel.Series.Add(LS);
        }
        public void TestMove()
        {
            PlotModel.Axes[0].Reset();
        }
        public void AddPoint()
        {
            do
            {
                LS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(++_NumberOf, rnd.Next(1, 10)));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                EndPosition += 1;
                LA.Maximum = EndPosition+3;
                LA.Minimum = EndPosition;
                Update();
            } while (true);
        }
        public void Update()
        {
            PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
        }
    }
    public delegate void BeginUpdate();
    private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private long lastUpdateMilliSeconds;
    DataGeneration Data;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        Data = new DataGeneration(1);
        BeginUpdate BU = new BeginUpdate(Data.AddPoint);
        IAsyncResult result = BU.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        this.DataContext = Data;
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTargetRendering;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void CompositionTargetRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > lastUpdateMilliSeconds + 300)
        {
            Data.Update();
        }
    }
}
}
```

why it firing when I make double click on OxyPlot? Genaraly i am trying to pan chart by left mousebutton.It's implemented in oxyplot by default(right mouse button).

Comment: Why you are not using PlotController class for it?